# how can I make transition animation without resizing the contents of my Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I'm using this project [Video-Chat-Application](https://github.com/iitbaakash/Video-Chat-application) and I want to change the collapse animation to keep the size of contents instead of resizing them, to explain more I'm going to explain my question with pictures.
The current animation is resizing the contents of the frag when it collapses like this :

[image] ==================> [image]

but what I want is something like this :

[image]

Is it possible to do that with Fragments ?
And here is my code :

```
public class Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/*
.
.
.
*/  
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (isExpanded) {
        isExpanded = false;
        MenuList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        MenuList.startAnimation(new CollapseAnimation(DynamicFragParent, (int) (screenWidth * 0.72), 0.01));
    } else {
        isExpanded = true;
        MenuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MenuList.startAnimation(new ExpandAnimation(DynamicFragParent, (int) (screenWidth * 0.72), 0.01));
    }
}
}
```

and this is my ListFrag class :

```
public class MenuFrag extends ListFragment {
/*
.
.
.
*/
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        HomeFrag homeFrag = new HomeFrag ();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contents, homeFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        DisconnectFrag disconnectFrag = new DisconnectFrag ();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contents, disconnectFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

it's because the views that are been resized have their width with `match_parent` value
set it to any other value ... try `wrap_content` instead